# How to join two tables together with columns that aren't keys (in NHibernate)?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent

I have one table that has an Id (PK) and another table with a bunch of information.  There will be a one-to-many relationship from the first table to some data in the second table, but there's no FK's anywhere.  So I want to do an inner join on table1.Id with table2.OtherId.

I've got my Model set up with an IList and in my table1 map I have:

```
HasMany(x => x.Properties).KeyColumn("table2id");
```

but I guess since it doesn't know what to join that column with in the first table, it won't work.  I know the table2 model is working correctly because I've tried it on its own and I get all the correct data.  It's just this HasMany thing that's getting messed up.

I've looked at the other "related" questions here on SO but I can't see anything that works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turned out that I needed to have `References` in the Table2 mapping onto Table1.  And then simply `HasMany(x => x.Properties).Inverse.Cascade.None()` in the Table1 Mapping sorted it out.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to have a FK relationship but the column specified in KeyColumn must be the primary key of table2. I don't know of a workaround.

Comment: I've tried property-ref but I still have the same problem (getting this "association references unmapped class" error)